# Region enclosed by circle and line help

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

Need some help on a calculus assignment. Completely stumped and my long distance lecturers are non existent (as always) and my study guide doesn't have enough examples to be useful for this question.

So the full question is

Let R be the Region enclosed in the circle $x^2+y^2=1$ and below the line $y=x+1$

(a) Sketch the Region R and find the points of intersection (see image below)

[image]

b) Is R a Type I region? If yes describe it as a Type I region. If not , describe it as a union of Type I regions. Use set builder notation

c) Same as question b but uses Type II region

Now I've not been able to answer b) or c). This is either because my region is wrong or because I don't understand how the region can be Type I or Type II without it being a union in set builder notation

PS: Should I be thinking of using polar coordinates? The reason I think not is the question is identified as being part of a section of work that excludes the polar coordinates, so I think it should be ignored for now (unless it's the only solution)

Comment: Your question sounds incomplete, what are you asked to do?

Comment: Sorry, a bit late and tired. Reworded my question, hopefully my question is clearer.

Comment: Your sketch of the region seems correct, but it is not clear what is your question. And what you means by Type 1 and Type regions?

Comment: Type I and Type II region in my study guide is defined as regions with upper or lower bounds of functions of x or functions of  y (if that makes sense)

Comment: Well, clearly the region is of neither type I or type II. I suppose you could describe it as the union of regions with $-1\le x \le 0$ and $0 \le x \le 1$.

Comment: This is where my problem is. To me it would make sense to have it as union of either Type I or Type II. Could it be a mistake in the question?  This has happened on several subjects and wouldn't surprise me.

Unless this is some sort of trick question and/or I'm suppose to use another method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Type I:
The question is can the region be described as a region between two constants, and two functions over $x$, or a union of such regions.
Is the region of Type I? No, so let's find a union:

Separate the region along the line $x=0$ and call the regions $D_1$ and $D_2$.

$D_1$ can be described as the region with the boundaries of $f\left(x \right) = x+1$ and $g\left(x \right) = -\sqrt{ \left(1-x^2 \right)}$ on the domain of $-1\le x \le 0$

$D_2$ can be described as the region with the boundaries of $h\left(x \right) = \sqrt{ \left(1-x^2 \right)}$ and $k\left(x \right) = -\sqrt{ \left(1-x^2 \right)}$ on the domain of $0\le x \le -1$

Both of these regions are of Type I.

The same logic follows for Type II.

Comment: I understand! Thank so much! I was on the right track at least.